# Should we have a canonical virtualenv question?

Tags: discussion, canonical

I realize, of course, that [virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualenv) is a whole tag, and having a single question summarizing the whole topic is beyond the scope of the site.  I want an introductory question that goes over enough of the basics to serve as a reasonable dupe target for questions about Python packaging where a virtualenv is obviously the correct answer.

Some of the questions in [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22sudo%20pip%20install%22%20is%3aquestion) are the kinds of questions I am thinking of.  Most of the time, `sudo pip install foo` is a Bad Idea, or at least an idea which merits a lot of long and hard thought about whether it's workable in a given scenario.  Unfortunately, this response often gets a lot of resistance from the asker, who's already learned just enough to conclude that "Installing software is a simple problem, which in the Python universe is solved with Pip, therefore any solution which involves some random tool that isn't Python or Pip must be over-engineered."

A typical example, minus the OP pushback, can be found in the search result with the most votes:

[OSX El Capitan: sudo pip install OSError: [Errno: 1] Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted)

In this case, the OP tried to run `sudo pip install` and it broke horribly.  The solution was to use a virtualenv instead.

If you remove `is:question` from that search, or [change it to `is:answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sudo+pip+install%22+is%3Aanswer), you can also see that our answerers are giving out a lot of bad or at least questionable advice.  Some of these answers may be reasonable depending on the specific circumstances of the question, but I doubt that applies to every last one of these answers.

I want a canonical question/answer that, at a minimum:

- Explains briefly what a virtualenv is.
- Explains why running commands such as `sudo pip install foo` is a bad idea.
- Provides basic instructions for creating a virtualenv and installing things into it.

  - This should cover both Python 2.7 and Python 3+, given a reasonably typical system configuration (e.g. Windows/Mac/Ubuntu).  Note that [ensurepip not existing is apparently considered "reasonable" by some people](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847).
- Is sufficiently compelling and results-oriented that users who want everything to "just work" will not reject virtualenv as overly complicated after reading one or two paragraphs of the answer.  For example, while inside the virtualenv:

  - Show that `python` runs the preferred Python version regardless of the system version.
  - Show that `pip install foo` works, no sudo required.
  - Perhaps demonstrate `pip freeze`/`pip install -r`.
- Briefly name-drops `pip install --user` for people who absolutely insist on making things difficult for themselves.

The title of this question would probably be something like this:

> What is a virtualenv and why should I use one?

**Is it a good idea to create this canonical question?**

(Alternatively, does a suitable Q/A pair already exist for this?  I searched a bit but couldn't really find anything.)

---

**And created!**  Given the positive response to this question, I went ahead and [posted a basic Q&A on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one/41972262#41972262).  The answer is community wiki because A) I don't need the rep and B) I'd appreciate help editing it into shape.  Please feel free to edit the answer, or the question, if you see any way of improving either of them.

Comment: Why not discuss this in the [Python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)? The community around that chatroom has, in the past, curated some very well received canonical questions (see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658) for a good example).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Because it's almost midnight local time and I have to get up tomorrow.

Comment: Tomorrow is another day :-) I've dropped a link to the post in the room.

Comment: Well, tomorrow is another day... come then :D

Comment: well here is yet another for that dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979428/use-pip-python-django-instead-apt

Answer (score 10):

I finished writing the virtualenvs bit of "Python in a Nutshell" a while ago, so I'll be well-placed to help with a canonical question. Until the value of the documentation section is established, however, I don't have any particular wish to participate in it.

Happy to help with a canonical question, though.

Comment: I created it and updated the meta question.  It's a community wiki, so feel free to contribute directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/virtualenv/info) is for. See [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) for example.

The problem is of course that very few people ever find them, let alone new users. But that's something I hope the SE designers are working on.

Answer (score -2):

This seems like a good fit for documentation. From the [overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation)

> Documentation is broad, and it is a general reference. You aren't documenting a specific problem you're facing, you're helping others deal with an entire class of problems by documenting.

which is similar to your aim of having an "introductory" source that "goes over enough of the basics to serve as a reasonable dupe target." You can then link to the canonical documentation topic when duplicates occur.

The topic page for virtualenv is currently [In Proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/virtualenv).

Comment: The official documentation of Python is so good that the corresponding SO Documentation pages are...not so good. I'd rather we keep canonicals on main (and everything else, for that matter).

Comment: The problem is, you can't close a question as a duplicate of a Documentation topic/example.